# javascript validation in VS2017 in other folder than scripts

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 on build execution validates and displays errors for any javascript file found in ProjectDir/Scripts/ folder
Is it possible to enable this feature for another directory?